# Can Scala constrain an object graph so that only those objects relevant to the context are visible?

Tags: scala, abstraction, dci, typeclass

Is there a way to use Scala's type-system to concisely specify the context-relevant subgraph of a complete object graph?

DCI argues that you often have a fairly complex object graph but in any one use-case you often only want to work with a sub-graph. You have a `Foo` that has a `Bar` and a `Bat`, but when you're in use-case 1, you only care about the `Bar` and when in use-case 2, only about the `Bat`.

For instance, let's say that you have this structure, and the Role1 use-case requires `Foo->Bar->Baz->Bin` and Role2 use-case requires `Foo->Bat->Baz->Buz`:

```
class Foo{
   val bar = new Bar() //Only relevant to Role 1
   val bat = new Bat() //Only relevant to Role 2 
}

class Bar {
   val baz = new Baz() 
}

class Bat {
   val baz = new Baz()
}

//Relevant to both Role 1 and 2 (via Bar or Bat)
class Baz {
  val bin = new Bin() //Only relevant to Role 1
  val buz = new Buz() //Only relevant to Role 2
}

class Bin{}
class Buz{}
```

It's easy to see how you can constrain access in **a single class** by using traits:

```
trait FooInRole1 { def bar : Bar }  //Define accessor in trait
s/Foo/Foo extends FooInRole1/       //Change Foo's declaration to implement trait
val f : FooInRole1 = new Foo        //LHS is i'face, RHS is implementation
//f.bat <--Compile error              Irrelevant field is not available. \o/
```

**But** you have to repeat this pattern for every object relevant to the use-case. (For instance, you need a `BazInRole1` to access `bin` and a `BazInRole2` to access `biz`)

My question is whether there's some way to avoid writing all these easy-to-get-wrong, namespace-crowding traits. For instance, I could imagine something like this code (that doesn't compile):

```
class Foo[T] {
  T match { 
    case r1 : Role1 => def bar : Bar[T]
    case r2 : Role2 => def bat : Bat[T]
    case _ => //Nothing
  }
}

val fInRole1 = new Foo[Role1] //Provides Foo->Bar->Baz->Bin
val fInRole2 = new Foo[Role2] //Provides Foo->Bat->Baz->Buz
```

It seems like Scala's type-system is expressive enough to do something like this, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: I think something like this can be achieved with type-classes. Just make the type-class the view on the object graph and access and manipulate its contents only through the type-class.

Answer (score 1):

Not extremely concise, and the members are there, just impossible to use, but maybe going in this direction would be acceptable?

```
class Foo[R] {
  def bar(implicit ev: R <:< Role1) = new Bar[R] //Only relevant to Role 1
  def bat(implicit ev: R <:< Role2) = new Bat[R] //Only relevant to Role 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly (which I'm not sure of) you want `Foo` to provide one of either `bar` or `bat` depending on the type parameter of `Foo`.

My first shot would be:

```
class Bar
class Bat

trait BarExt { def bar = new Bar }
trait BatExt { def bat = new Bat }

trait Role
case object Role1 extends Role
case object Role2 extends Role

trait RoleProvider[From <: Role, To] {
  def apply(): To
}

object RoleProvider {
  implicit val r1 = new RoleProvider[Role1.type, Foo[Role1.type] with BarExt] {
    def apply() = new Foo[Role1.type] with BarExt
  }

  implicit val r2 = new RoleProvider[Role2.type, Foo[Role2.type] with BatExt] {
    def apply() = new Foo[Role2.type] with BatExt
  }
}

class Foo[T <: Role]

object Foo {
  def create[T <: Role, To](f: T)(implicit rp: RoleProvider[T,To]): To = rp()
}
```

so that

```
scala> Foo.create(Role1)
res1: Foo[Role1.type] with BarExt = RoleProvider$$anon$3$$anon$1@187b2d93    scala> Foo.create(Role1).bar

scala> Foo.create(Role1).bar
res2: Bar = Bar@7ea4b9da

scala> Foo.create(Role1).bat
<console>:12: error: value bat is not a member of Foo[Role1.type] with BarExt
              Foo.create(Role1).bat
```

and

```
scala> Foo.create(Role2).bat
res3: Bat = Bat@56352b57

scala> Foo.create(Role2).bar
<console>:12: error: value bar is not a member of Foo[Role2.type] with BatExt
              Foo.create(Role2).bar
```

One could get rid of `BarExt` and `BatExt` by pulling the corresponding declarations into the definitions of `r1` and `r2`, however I find it "harder" to work with that:

```
implicit val r1 = new RoleProvider[Role1.type, Foo[Role1.type] { val bar: Bar }] {
  def apply() = new Foo[Role1.type] { val bar = new Bar }
}

implicit val r2 = new RoleProvider[Role2.type, Foo[Role2.type] { val bat: Bat }] {
  def apply() = new Foo[Role2.type] { val bat = new Bat }
}
```

At the bottom line, I'm still not convinced that this is exactly what you've been asking for, or is it?

Comment: I don't think it's exactly what I'm looking for. Think about Baz (or, worse, a graph of 20 classes with cross-references). To ensure that Baz.bin is only available in Role1, don't I have to define a trait (xExt) per object per role and write a conversion fn per edge? Maybe that's the best that can be done, but I was *hoping* to find a  way to "cascade" the type-parameter from Foo to Baz concisely. Does that make sense?

Comment: So *all* methods are supposed to be contained in the original graph but when "viewing" the graph from a certain role, only a subset of those methods are exposed? I'm assuming that by "subgraph" you're referring to the same set of nodes but with different, type-dependent roles?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm hoping for.

Comment: Would it make sense to define a `toRole[T]` method for each node that returns a reference of the desired type? You could probably use the same implicit mechanism as in the example above.

Comment: Yes, *something* like toRole or RoleAdapter[T <: Role, U <: TypeThatCanAssumeRole] : U[T] would be nice and concise. You certainly cannot avoid writing *somewhere* that "Role1 means Foo with Bar, Baz with Bin, etc." It's just that you want that definition to be explicit and in a single place. And then if you have, as you say, some kind of toRole / inRole factory that takes care of the wiring in a single place.

Answer (score 0):

In [this artima article](http://www.artima.com/articles/dci_vision.html) on DCI, the author presents a way to get a DCI architecture in Scala, which looks like what you are aiming for.

The basic idea is to define the methods that are relevant to your use-case in a trait, but instead of your approach it uses a self-type annotation to ensure it is an object of a certain base class.

So to make this a bit more approachable: you have a Data-class `Data`, which contains the elementary components of your data objects. When you want to realize a certain use-case, which likes to consider a `Data` object in a certain role `Role` you can prepare the role like this:

```
trait Role { self : Data => 
  def methodForOnlyThisUseCase = {...}
}
```

For execution of the use-case, you then create an object specific to this role via:

```
val myUseCaseObject = new Data with Role
```

Like this, the object `myUseCaseObject` is limited to exactly its `Data` constituents and the methods required for its role in the given use-case.

If it gets more complex, you may have to create something like a pseudo role trait, which defines the methods common to multiple use-cases. The self-type annotation of the use-case role would then point back to this pseudo trait, whereas the pseudo traits self-type annotation points to the corresponding data class.

Comment: Yes, that's an important article about DCI, and my question starts from this type of design, but the issue is that you have to explicitly write a trait for every class-in-role. In my example, you end up having to create a trait FooInRole1, FooInRole2 and BazInRole1, BazInRole2, and you even end up having to create a BarInRole1 in order to "pass through" the Role type to Baz. It *may be* that this is as good as you can do, but it seems like there ought to be a way to avoid so much namespace clutter.